# different insert position with stringstream

Tags: c++, stl, stringstream

I struggle to understand the different behaviours of stringstream from the following code. Can someone shed a light on how stream internally works?

```
int main(){
    string str = "123";  
    stringstream ss(str);
    cout << ss.str() <<endl;  
    ss << str;
    cout << ss.str() <<endl;
}
```

output:

123

123

```
int main(){
    string str = "123";  
    stringstream ss;
    ss << str;
    cout << ss.str() <<endl;  
    ss << str;
    cout << ss.str() <<endl;
}
```

output:

123

123123

Comment: +1 Good question. I hate such subtleties (inconsistencies?), though.

Comment: @Nawaz, I agree, it is quite vague, you can edit with a better one.

Comment: Question is pretty much clear. I'm talking about the behavior of the language (and the library).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because the actual write position isn't updated, so when you in the first example do

```
ss << str;
```

you *overwrite* the current string.

Use the flag `std::ios_base::ate` to the constructor of the string stream

```
std::stringstream ss(str,
    std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::ate);
```

to position the read/write pointers at the end.

See the example in [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream/basic_stringstream).

And it's like that for all streams, when you open a file stream the positions are also at the start.

Comment: You need `std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::ate` for that to work.

Comment: @JesseGood Check the linked reference, it's added by the constructor itself.

Comment: You linked to `basic_ostringstream`. We are dealing with `basic_stringstream`.

Answer (score 3):

`std::stringstream` object internally remembers the position, where the writing ended last time. This is updated when you use `<<` operator, but not when you use some string to construct this stream:

```
stringstream ss(str);
cout << ss.tellp() <<endl;  
ss << str;
cout << ss.tellp() <<endl;
```

outputs:

```
0
3
```

i.e. by the time first `ss << str;` is executed, it just uses "123" to rewrite "123", which is already there.
You could use `setp` to *set the position where the next character is to be inserted*:

```
stringstream ss(str);
cout << ss.str() <<endl;  
ss.seekp(3);                 // <-- sets outPUT position
ss << str;
cout << ss.str() <<endl;
```

Alternatively you might set the mode, which will make sure that this position will be set to the end before every write operation using `std::stringstream::app` or you can use `std::ios_base::ate`, which seeks to the end of stream immediately after open:

```
stringstream ss(str, std::stringstream::out | std::stringstream::app);
```

Comment: I think anybody with some knowledge of C++ can *guess* that. But what is required by the spec? and can you please quote the reference that *requires* this? Or maybe, it is a bug in the compilers?

Comment: @Nawaz It's like that for all streams. You have to specifically add the `std::ios_base::ate` to tell the stream to go to the end.

Answer (score 1):

Constructing an `std::stringstream` sets the position to the beginning of the stream. The position is updated after writing to the stream or when calling the appropriate seek method.